# HTML button, apache.http.client. sending post request to it

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Long story short I having an issue sending post request to sever, after completing my first one. This is being done in java.

Basically my question is using apache http client is it possible to press a button as I can't find any other away around this, (I am normally use selenium but am attempting to save ram by removing the browser so using post request instead)

Here is an example of html code:

I have look into making post request to the sever by using network tab in chrome tried multiple things but wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi! It seems like you wanted to post code, but nothing is there.

Comment: Hey, I just want to post html code, <input type="submit" value="Reply" accesskey="s" class="button primary"> , I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is even possible.

Comment: Click a button and send a http request are two different things. Find out what the button does "onclick" and simulate that.